# PDFView on landscape

Tags: android, androidpdfviewer

I am trying to open local Pdf file from Assest folder in android studio platform using [barteksc] library. I downloaded the library and managed to open the pdf file. However, when I orient the emulator to landscape mode the pdf width will not fit the screen. I googled the issue and the solution is to use the following piece of code.

```
Configurator.onRender(new OnRenderListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInitiallyRendered(int pages, float pageWidth, float pageHeight) {
        pdfView.fitToWidth(); // optionally pass page number
    }
});
```

But, I do not know how to implement this code. I wrote the following :

```
public class Pdf extends AppCompatActivity {
PDFView pdfview;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pdf);
        pdfview=(PDFView)findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        pdfview.fromAsset("h.pdf").load();

        PDFView.Configurator.onRender(new OnRenderListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitiallyRendered(int pages, float pageWidth, float pageHeight) {
                pdfview.fitToWidth(); // optionally pass page number
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And I got this error ...

Non-static method 'onRender(com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnRenderListener)' cannot be referenced from a static context

Plese show me how can I fix this issue. Loads of thanks in advance for any help you may lend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below shows how to use that method

```
            pdfView.fromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE)
            .defaultPage(pageNumber)
            .enableSwipe(true)
            .enableDoubletap(true)
            .swipeVertical(false)
            .showMinimap(false)
            .onRender(new OnRenderListener() {
             @Override
             public void onInitiallyRendered(int pages, float pageWidth, 
             float pageHeight) {
            pdfview.fitToWidth(); // optionally pass page number
              }
             });
             .onLoad(this)
             .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
            .load();
```